# Build Error in the "refclock.h" header file, a part of Windows platform SDK

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, sdk

I am building a VC++ solution & using Win& SDK & Win8 SDK (including these paths in LIB & INCLUDE settings of VS2008). 
But I am getting the following build error in refclock.h header file.
I don't understand how can we get the error in a standard MSFT header file. Can anyone kindly help me in getting this fixed?

```
c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(80) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CAMSchedule'
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(139) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(139) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(139) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(139) : warning C4183: 'GetSchedule': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(178) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(178) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(178) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(139) : error C2065: 'm_pSchedule' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(166) : error C2065: 'm_pSchedule' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses\refclock.h(166) : error C2227: left of '->GetEvent' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Comment: Do you have any declarations or header-file includes before this file is included? Maybe there's a missing semicolon there somewhere?

Comment: In the code I am no where directly including refclock.h i.e there is no refreence to refclock.h in the source code. But I really don't understand how is this coming?

Answer (score 11):

It's caused by an error in the refclock.h header and the order your include directories are specified in Visual Studio.

You need to have the BaseClasses directory (Samples/Multimedia/DirectShow) **before** the SDK include directory, since they both have a schedule.h file and refclock.h uses <> not "" for the include.